# Can you have use () when using Axure Math functions

Tags: axure

I'm creating an Axure prototype and have recently found out about the new math functions (as of version 6). (For clarity - Axure allows you to publish wire frames as a prototype and you can use the Math functions to dynamically calculate values to simulate 'add to basket/pricing functionality etc.)

Is it possible to do more complex calculations such as

```
[[((GVar1+0)*LVAR1) + ((GVar1+10)*LVAR2)]]
```

If not, does anyone have any suggestion of how I can dynamically calculate the price of something based upon a base price (GVar1) + selection uplift (0,10) times by the selected quantity LVAR1.

Comment: Since Axure is a prototyping tool - have you considered winging it? I mean, it doesn't generate anything reusable, and even though I to can sometimes get caught up in the near-to-programming options, it seldom pays off. I try to disciplin myself to only illustrating the interaction to the point where the user can get the idea/try a pree-scripted example

Comment: In this instance we're using the prototype for a test and calculating the values are important to understanding the experience. (other than that i agree)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can use brackets to aggregate values.